# 'Засирать' or 'засерать'?

Tags: грамматика

'Засрать' (from 'срать') is а rude Russian verb means just about 'to dirty off' (literally: to grime smth with feces). What is the correct form of its imperfect: 'засирать' or 'засерать'? And why so?
//---------
Как будет несовершенный вид к засрать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Засирать* should be correct; compare *забрать/забирать* and *задрать/задирать*, as well as a few verbs with a differently patterned infinitive but the same present-tense stem: *запереть (запру) — запирать, замереть (замру) — замирать*, etc.

Comment: Yes, all right.)))

Answer (score 0):

I would consider засерать as pretty archaic, coming from the form засерить. In modern language, засирать is more natural.

Comment: I would consider *засерать* a spelling mistake, both now and centuries ago. Where does *засерить* even come from? Looks so counter-etymological it's probably relatively new.

Comment: Well, probably not archaic but regional. I have heard серить a lot from elder people, but my experience is biased towards Ukrainian-ish dialects.

Comment: @Nikolay Ershov, I've heard it few times in the forms 'Хватит серить", 'насерили', etc. But it sounds a bit dialectic (South of Russia and Ural region).

Comment: @GeorgeShuklin could it be a plenivocal infinitive (like *тереть*) with shifted stress due to semantic reasons (disambiguation from *сереть=>серею*), later reinterpreted as 2nd conjugation?